# Select DISTINCT with JOIN not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been working on this for days... I'm just learning and I'm reading all the tutorials but this just will not work for me! I know the problem has many answers but I must be typing something wrong...

1KaraokeDJ = 1KaraokeDJcopy because I couldn't figure out the use of AS to create a temp for use in the JOIN with the DISTINCT in 1 SELECT

ID is primary unique key
Artist, Title, Disc, Track, Brand are all needed in the output

When using DISTINCT Title, Brand the result only has those 2 columns 
So I figured I would have to JOIN ON ID so I could have the Distinct records and still have all columns... There is probably a better way to do this but that's all I could find out reading the various tutorials.

```
<?php ...
$searchterm="call me";
$searchresults=$db->query("select DISTINCT Title, Brand from 1KaraokeDJcopy JOIN 1KaraokeDJ ON 1KaraokeDJcopy.ID=1KaraokeDJ.ID where Title like '%$searchterm%' limit 100");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($searchresults) > 0) {
          while($descri=mysqli_fetch_object($searchresults)) { ?>
            <div class="reslt">
              <h3 id="results">
                <?php
                  echo $descri->Artist); echo " - ";
                  echo $descri->Title);
                ?>
              </h3>
              <p class="Description">
                <?php
                  echo $descri->Brand; echo " - ";
                  echo $descri->Disc); echo " - ";
                  echo $descri->Track;
                ?>
              </p>
              <hr>
            </div>
          <?php } ?>
```

I get no query with the above code (print_r($searchresults); is null)

```
$searchresults=$db->query("select * from 1KaraokeDJ where Title like '%$searchterm%' order by Artist, Disc limit 100");
```

Produces 21 results with 4 duplicates (duplicate Brand because same song on several Discs even though different Disc number ie CB5016-01 and CBEP467-1 but both Brand is Chartbuster)

```
$searchresults=$db->query("select DISTINCT Title, Brand from 1KaraokeDJ where Title like '%$searchterm%' limit 100");
```

Produces the correct 17 results but my output no longer contains Artist, Disc, Track

Table structure for table `1KaraokeDJ`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `1KaraokeDJ` (
  `Disc` varchar(12) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Track` enum('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36') COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Artist` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Brand` enum('Chartbuster','DKKaraoke','Karaoke Hits','Sound Choice','Sunfly') COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `ID` smallint(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `Disc` (`Disc`),
  KEY `Artist` (`Artist`),
  KEY `Title` (`Title`),
  KEY `Brand` (`Brand`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Artist_2` (`Artist`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Title_2` (`Title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=28618 ;
```

Comment: Could you provide a mysql table schema?

Comment: Add structure. I can probably drop some keys but I've been playing with various settings for days

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 0: Turn on error_reporting by adding this line to your PHP files

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Step 0.1: Try queries directly in MySQL if they are not working as desired.

1. I don't see why you need a join. You are joining the table to itself on ID=ID, which accomplishes nothing.

1.1 (You don't need to do this but for completeness)
    To JOIN a table to itself the syntax would be

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table1 as table1copy ON table1.col1 = table1copy.col2
```

2. Every column you want in the output needs to be in your `SELECT` clause.

   `SELECT Artist, Title, Brand, Disc, Track FROM ...`
3. Your not actually getting duplicates if there is even one column different. That's not a duplicate. I don't totally understand your desired result but i think [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) might help.

Comment: In the end Select * from 1KaraokeDJ GROUP BY Artist, Title, Brand solved it. Not sure why I thought distinct had to be used? Like I said, I'm learning! Also, turning on error reporting REALLY helped...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write columns name on the query, if you write

```
select DISTINCT Title, Brand from 1KaraokeDJ where Title like '%$searchterm%' limit 100
```

Query will select only `DISTINCT Title` and `Brand`. Only `*` selects all columns, otherwise you have to specify all of them, so you should write your query like this:

```
select DISTINCT Title, Brand,Artist,Disc,Track from 1KaraokeDJ where Title like '%$searchterm%' limit 100
```

Side note: are you escaping `$searchterm` value and using `mysqli_` or `PDO` functions? If not, you should, just to avoid `SQL Injections` :)

Comment: $searchterm is set by a post form. In my above code I just shortened it all... Should I esc the imputed text from the form?

Comment: Yes you should, for example, if you're using `mysqli_` functions use `mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$searchterm)`. Remember, NEVER trust user inputs :)

Comment: I'm using $searchterm=strtoupper($_SESSION['searchterm']); echo str_ireplace($searchterm, '<span class="highlight">'.$searchterm."</span>", $descri->Artist); do I also need to esc it?

Comment: If you take it by a form submit where user can input, I guess you should escape it

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ok, first of all in your query you are not providing from which table you are taking the columns and which table column has to match the value. The query should look like:

```
$searchresults=$db->query("select DISTINCT 1KaraokeDJcopy.Title, 1KaraokeDJcopy.Brand from 1KaraokeDJcopy JOIN 1KaraokeDJ ON 1KaraokeDJcopy.ID=1KaraokeDJ.ID where 1KaraokeDJcopy.Title like '%$searchterm%' limit 100");
```

Secondly, its hard to say without having your schema presented and all DB structure, but I would do it with this query (without any joins, distinct value, but having group by):

```
$searchresults=$db->query("select * from 1KaraokeDJ where Title like '%$searchterm%' group by Title, Brand limit 100");
```